# How to Programmatically Scroll Android WebView

Tags: android, scroll, webview

I'm trying to programmatically scroll a WebView to the location of a particular element in the DOM tree.  But so far I haven't been able to get the WebView to respond to scroll requests.  I've tried calling JavaScript that uses `window.scrollTo(...)`, but the WebView doesn't respond.  On the Java side, I've tried calling the `WebView.flingScroll(...)` method.  WebView will respond to `flingScroll`, but what I need is a `scrollTo(...)` capability.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I've found a better answer to this issue.  It turns out that `WebView` does have `scrollTo()`, `getScrollX()` and `getScrollY()` methods as you'd expect.  They're a bit hidden in the documentation because they're inherited from `View` (via `AbsoluteLayout` -> `ViewGroup` -> `View`).  This is obviously a better way to manipulate the `WebView`'s scroll position than the somewhat cumbersome JavaScript interface.

Comment: It's nice of you to come back and add this :)

Comment: it is good solution. but i want to do some extra. I have one html file which contain the school lesson(with some tag), and one audio file which contain the recording of explanation of that lesson. I want to scroll my web view(which contain the html file) according to the audio file which is play in background. if i forward the audio file then my scroll also move on that position where the audio is currently play. will u have any suggestion on same.

Comment: @Steve: it work fine for me, but i want to scroll web view at top(i.e. where web view is start). i am using mScrollView.scrollTo(0.mScrollView.getScrollY()) but it wont work.

Comment: @SteveLiddle: It work fine for scroll view but not for webView. I want to apply it for webView. And one more think i want ur suggestion, i want to auto scroll web view to particular position at some interval of time. I am using findAll("tag") and findNext(true) for that. It work fine but it scroll till "tag" at the bottom of screen, i want to scroll it till "tag" at top of screen. Thanks.

Comment: @SteveLiddle How do you get the position of the DOM element you wish to scroll to then? A Javascript interface?

Comment: @Maarten, an element can report its position and you can get that by writing some JavaScript.  I think anything you want to do with the DOM tree will need to happen in JavaScript, not Objective-C.

Answer (score 13):

It turns out that the `window.scrollTo()` DOES work, you just can't add your own method named `scrollTo()`.  For some reason my own `scrollTo()` method was being invoked when I called `window.scrollTo()`.

So, in summary, to scroll a WebView to a particular DOM element, write a `JavaScript` function to do the scrolling:

```
function scrollToElement(id) {
    var elem = document.getElementById(id);
    var x = 0;
    var y = 0;

    while (elem != null) {
        x += elem.offsetLeft;
        y += elem.offsetTop;
        elem = elem.offsetParent;
    }
    window.scrollTo(x, y);
}
```

and then from your Android app (Java code), tell your WebView to load a URL:

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:scrollToElement('" + elemId + "')");
```

There are some issues with this approach, such as the scroll will not be nicely animated, but the general mechanism works.

The DOM window object does report the current scroll position of the WebView correctly (see `window.pageXOffset`, `window.pageYOffset` or `window.scrollX`, `window.scrollY)`.  If you just want to know the current scroll position of the WebView, write some JavaScript to call your Java code and pass along the X/Y offsets.

Comment: That happens because when declaring a function in the global scope, it's actually being declared as a property on the global `window` object.

Answer (score 0):

**You cannot do that using Java Code**.

For alls who are stuck at this problem, I have some conclusion about scrolling a webview in android.

- You cannot scroll a webview or get scrolling position using Java Code.
- You can only get layoutHeight, measuredHeight, contentHeight of a webview, nothing more. These are all the android api allowing you do in getting and setting scroll status.
- But, you can override the onScorllChanged to add a self-define listener for scrolling webview event(or fling event), you will be notified the origin position and the new position.
- Well, you can scroll to a position using JavaScript code, like the following, but the performance is really poor. If you want to scroll it frequently, please give it a second thought.

  > window.scrollTo(100,500)

Consider your situation and choose a proper solution. Also be noticed that fling and scroll are different things.

Answer (score 0):

```
    @Override
        public void onPageFinished(final WebView view, String url) {

            super.onPageFinished(view, url);

                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                                if (app.scrollCache.containsKey(app.srctid))
            {
                            app.scrollSpot=app.scrollCache.get(app.srctid); 
                            view.scrollTo(0,(int)app.scrollSpot);
                            }
                        pageFinished=true;
                        }
                    }, 200);


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The following one-line solution ensures that the selected element is brought into view, if it was not. This may be enough in some situations.

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('"+aID+"').scrollIntoView()");
```