# android scroll issues locking up browser

Tags: jquery, android, mobile, scroll, scrollbar

I have a page with a content section that is supposed to be scrollable, but when viewed on any android OS, it locks up the browser.  I've got a test page here so that you can see what I'm talking about.

http://www.fspt.org/mdportal/test.html

and in case you were too pressed for time to go to the page and hit view source, here's a txt file of the source:

http://www.fspt.org/mdportal/test.txt

the content section is the names part of the page and is generated with this CSS

```
#nextsection
{
width: 450px;
height: 335px;
text-align: left;
border: 0px;
padding: 0;
margin: 0 auto;
margin-top: 0px;
overflow:auto;
}
```

I would have thought that overflow:auto would have taken care of the situation, but no scrollbar ever becomes available regardless of what I do, and scrolling in the section just locks it up.  if the page is viewed on an iOS device, you can use two fingers to scroll, but when viewed on an android, nothing.

you may also notice some issues with the jquery on the android browser.  any help there is appreciated as well, though thats probably better suited for a different question.

any help is appreciated.  thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This may be related to known scrolling issues on Android: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2118. You may want to implement your own scroll, which there are a few examples of here on SO: [How to Programmatically Scroll Android WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2238938/how-to-programmatically-scroll-android-webview)

Comment: Thank you for the link to the android issues.  it's helpful to know it isn't just my page.  i'm not sure how i'm going to handle this yet.  it's pretty disheartening to know this issue has been out there for 2 years and google hasn't fixed something as universal as overflow: auto;

Comment: Take a look at IScroll too: https://github.com/cubiq/iscroll - There are a lot of Jquery mobile developers that are using it.

Comment: I'm going with iscroll, but it's pretty brutal that the entire page has to be absolute positioned.  but if thats what gets it to work, so be it.