# scroller button in webview in android

Tags: android, webview

hi as you seen in the image the scroller . i want to implement this one in  the web-view how can i develop this feature in the web view . 
Thank you .[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is done on [`ListView`s](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) using  [`.setFastScrollEnabled(true);`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setFastScrollEnabled(boolean)).

It is not supported for `WebView`, however. That means you'd have to create your own `View` overlaying the `WebView` and have some item within it which [scrolls your `WebView`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2238938/how-to-programmatically-scroll-android-webview) in an [`OnTouchListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html)'s event.