# How to change WebView's webpage position? OSX

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, webview, webkit

Let's say I have a WebView that loads up twitter.com.
Here's what appears in my WebView:
[image]

And here's what I want to show:
[image]

How can I change the default Upper Left Corner position of website on the WebView to display another position of the same website?

Comment: What about this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2238938/how-to-programmatically-scroll-android-webview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get it to move using this (you need to set the frameLoadDelegate):

```
-(void)webView:(WebView *)sender didFinishLoadForFrame:(WebFrame *)frame
{

    if (frame == self.myWebview.mainFrame)
    {
        DOMDocument *mainDoc = [self.myWebview.mainFrame DOMDocument];
        DOMNodeList *list = [mainDoc getElementsByClassName:@"front-signin js-front-signin"];
        DOMNode *loginElement = [list item:0];
        NSRect myRect = loginElement.boundingBox;
        [self.myWebview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"window.scrollTo(%d,%d);", (int)myRect.origin.x, (int)myRect.origin.y]];
    }
}
```

"front-signin js-front-signin" being the name of the class used in the source html of www.twitter.com.

So it is failure prone to rely on that which could change at any time.

There is also in this case the header that doesn't move. So either account for it and display it, or move your view up the size of this header and hide it.

You need to adjust the scrollTo call to center it in your view.

And you might want to consider fading the view once it's loaded, cause the scroll is kind of jerky, and not very osx like.

But apart from this, it could work ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You could execute javascript in the UIWebView:

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.pageYOffset=200;"];
```

This should scroll the window down 200 pixels.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following on OS X:

> `[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"window.scrollTo(%f, %f)", xPos, yPos]];`

Answer (score -3):

You can also play with the webview's scrollView contentOffset.

```
UIWebView * webView = [[UIwebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.twitter.com"]]];
[webView.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(50, 60)];
[webView release];
```

Comment: i'm sorry but i'm using WebView for a OSX app and there's no 'scrollView' on the webView.