# How to set the position (scroll down position) of a webview after it is loaded?

Tags: android, webview

I am loading a selfmade html page into a webview and would like to set the position after it is loaded. In my case the page is showed up always at the top. Any hints how to do that.

My Code so far:

```
wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                int iSDKLevel=android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT ;
                if(iSDKLevel>=14){

                        wv.setScrollY(1000);

                }
            }
```

but onPageFinished is never called :-(

Any hints ?

Comment: when you say `position` what do you mean? maybe `automatically scroll`?

Comment: Yes I mean I like to show the text at a spcific position. For that I try to scroll down to position 1000 in my case.

Comment: For some time I saw something like  `android:descendantFocusability` in XML, check it, i can't remember how it works, maybe it helps you

Comment: Or you can implement auto-scrolling using  Handlers, wait, let me post an answer to do that

Comment: @mcflysoft remove `super.onPageFinished(view, url);` will onPageFinished now be called?

Answer (score 1):

Auto-scroll with Handlers:

```
private Runnable mScrollDown = new Runnable()
{
    public void run()
    {
        WebView webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
        webview.scrollBy(0, scrollSpeed);
        mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    }
};
```

I found too that link to scroll a WebView to a particular DOM element, check it.

[Scroll a WebView to a particular DOM element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2239301/3626214)