# How to scroll Android WebView programmatically to a specific element

Tags: android

I load an HTML string directly into a WebView with `loadDataWithBaseURL(null, html, null, null, null)` and later I'd like to be able to scroll programmatically to an internal element, e.g. `<p id="pos1">` or `<a name="pos1"></a>`

I found a similar question, where the answer was to use javascript:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2239301/2534762

But is that really the only way? Isn't there another simple way to say directly to a WebView: "go to #pos1" without having to embed a script in every HTML page that you want to scroll? It seems to me a common task begging for a simple solution, but apparently I'm wrong... or is there a way to do that, maybe calling loadUrl or loadDataWithBaseURL in some particular way?

Answer (score 1):

I found that I don't need to embed JavaScript in the HTML page, as suggested in [that other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2239301/2534762), I can instead write one line of JavaScript directly in the URL:

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('"+aID+"').scrollIntoView()");
```

Comment: hi @MMazzon. what is the html to load is thru a URL? ex. webView.loadUrl('www.company.com/policy')

Comment: @iori24 I'm loading my own HTML, generated by my app, and not an external web page. What I wanted to do later was scroll to a given position in that page, which I achieved with the code above (I don't rememebr exactly, it was some time ago)